# How common is an airliner activating reverse while still in flight?

Tags: landing, thrust-reverser

Around 1977, I watched a DC-9 landing at Guacimeta airport, Lanzarote, Canary Islands, Spain, opening the flaps reversing thrust of both engines just over the airstrip end, but some 9 feet over the ground. Of course, it fell down that height as fast as a stone. Is this usual?

Comment: The previous question was rather theoretical: What if? but this refers to an actually watched case. The underlying subject is the same, yes. It's up to you mixing or fusing both. Thanks. Salut +

Comment: Well, you ask whether it is common. The [other question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/why-cant-most-jets-safely-use-reverse-thrust-while-airborne) answers that one. The answer here should be clear: This is very, very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The system will allow deployment based on various criteria, and radio altitude height may be one of them, so even for a system not designed to operate "in flight", you still can deploy the TR's a few feet off the ground. Pretty ugly, rough touchdown when you do, though, and certainly not advised. How often that happens would be speculation, but probably very rare.